# Missing validation message in cakephp application

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to add a layout for a cakephp application but now my validation message is no longer being displayed. When validating a comment on a blog entry, the validation message thats suppose to be at the top is not displayed.

Comment: code pls? that way we may know what's wrong

Comment: As jun said, you should post the pertinent code. Particularly, the validation array (or wherever you're setting the error message), and the part of the template (ctp) that should display the message for starters.

Answer (score 0):

If you changing the layout means that you missed to add

```
<?php
if ($this->Session->check('Message.flash')){
  echo $this->Session->flash();
}
?>
```

before the

Other possible place is in the current controller.

Search if you have code like:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('...');
```

The first code is responsible for displaying the message, while the second one is responsible for setting the message.

But the code definitely will help more :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my add function in comments_controller.php

```
function add(){
    debug($this->data);
    //if the user submitted a comment post
    if (!empty($this->data)){

        //display the 'add view'    
        $this->Comment->create();

        if ($this->MathCaptcha->validates($this->data['Comment']['security_code'])) {

                if ($this->Comment->save($this->data)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Comment has been added.', true));
                    $this->redirect('/posts/index/'.$this->data['Comment']['post_id']);
                }
                //failed validation
                else{
                    debug($this->data);
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment could not be saved. Please try again.', true));

                }

        } 
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please enter the correct answer to the math question.', true));
            $this->redirect('/posts/index/'.$this->data['Comment']['post_id']);

        }
```

Here is my entry.ctp where my posts and comments reside:

```
<div id="article">


<h2><?php echo $entry[0]['Post']['title']; ?></h2>
<p class="date"><em>Modified:</em> <?php $date = new DateTime($entry[0]['Post']['modified']); 
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');?></p>
<p class="date"><em>Author:</em> <?php echo $entry[0]['User']['username']; ?></p>


<p class="intro"><?php echo $entry[0]['Post']['content']; ?></p>

<h2>Comments:</h2>
<div id="comments_success"></div>

<!-- show the comment -->


<?php

        echo $form->create('Comment', array('action' => 'add'));

        echo $form->input('name', array('class' => 'validate[required] text-input'));
        echo $form->input('email', array('class' => 'validate[required,custom[email]] text-input'));

        echo $form->input('text', array('id' => 'commenttext', 'type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Comment:', 'rows' => '10', 'class' => 'validate[required] text-input'));

        //captcha
        echo $form->input('security_code', array('label' => 'Please Enter the Sum of ' . $mathCaptcha));
        echo $form->input( 'Comment.post_id', array( 'value' => $entry[0]['Post']['id'] , 'type' => 'hidden') ); 

        echo $form->end('Submit');

    ?>

<!-- comments -->

<ol>

<?php
    foreach ($entry[0]['Comment'] as $comment) :                
?>
    <li>
        <h3><?php echo $comment['name']; ?></h3>    
        <p class="date"><em>Date:</em> <?php echo $comment['created']; ?></p>
        <p class="text"> <?php echo $comment['text']; ?></p>    
    </li>       
<?php
    endforeach; 
?>              
</ol>
</div>
```

This is the index function in my posts_controller

```
function index($entry_id = null) {

    if (isset($entry_id)){
        $entry = $this->Post->findAllById($entry_id);

        $comments = $this->Post->Comment->getCommentsFromPostID($entry_id);

        $this->set('entry' , $entry);
        $this->set('mathCaptcha', $this->MathCaptcha->generateEquation());
        $this->render('entry');

    }
    else{

        $posts = $this->Post->find('all');  

        $this->set(compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but ust make sure you have the following code somewhere visible in your app/views/layouts/default.ctp (or whatever is your layout for this application)

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

It will echo nothing if there is no message to be displayed, but if there is a message, then it will be output accordingly.